# Solve System of congruences

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I solve a system of linear congruences as such?

$$\begin{align*}
3x+2y+28z &= 9 \pmod {29} \\
 5x+27y+z &= 9 \pmod {29} \\
 2x+y+z &= 6 \pmod {29}
\end{align*}$$

I tried it this way as a system of equations, but no luck:

```
eqn1 = FullSimplify[{3*x + 2*y + 28*z == 9 + (29*i) &&
                     5*x + 27*y + z == 9 + (29*j) && 2*x + y + z == 6 + (29*k)}]
Table[FindInstance[eqn1, {x, y, z, i, j, k}, Integers, 1] ]
```

Additionally, how can I solve these linear congruences:

$$ 3x = 5 \pmod 6 $$

Tried this: No luck! `Reduce[3*x - 5 == 6, x, Modulus -> 6]`

and

$$ x^2 + x = 2 \pmod 8 $$

and

Find Multiplicative inverse of [5] in z42 ? which would mean $$ 5x + 42y =1 $$

and lastly:

Solve these systems in z11:

$$ [2][x]+[7][y] = [4] $$
$$ [3][x]+[2][y] = [9] $$

I'm pretty sure Mathematica can input and solve these.

Comment: `Solve[3 x == 5, x, Modulus -> 6]` , `Reduce[5 x + 42 y == 1, {x, y}, Modulus -> 42]` , `eq1 = 3 x +  2 y + 28 z == 9
eq2 = 5 x + 27 y + z == 9
eq3 = 2 x + y + z == 6
Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 29]`

Comment: Oddly enough none of them work for me. See outputs: (outputs)[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GiJgwN9kIMeKViGJTR68pI2gWRbjoBty/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Quit Kernel and start a fresh one, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, why does the kernel do that? is this a bug? The second one results in: x == 17 && y == C[1]   what is C1? and the first has no solutions?

Comment: Last one: `eq1 = 3 x +  4 y == 5
eq2 = 5 x + 2 y  == 1
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}, Modulus -> 11]` and I am glad it worked for you. C[1] would be, I am guessing, an integer modulo the same you started with. The first one gives me {{x->1}}.

Comment: BTW did you modify the 2 equations for the last one on purpose or was this an oversight? How did you get x->1 ? i didnt

Comment: Sorry about that; it was an oversight and you can quickly change it to the original question.

Comment: I still dont get why Reduce[5 x + 42 y == 1, {x, y}, Modulus -> 42] gives me x=17 and y=c1??  y is obviously -2  Also: shouldn't there be a large number of solutions to this anyway? As there is 1 eqn and 2 unknowns.

Comment: As far as I can explain it, try this: `t = Table[5 17 + 42 y, {y, 0, 41}]` and `Mod[#, 42] & /@ t` ;

Comment: Doesn't yield -2 still

Comment: `5*17==85==1` mod 42. And `42 y == 0` mod 42, regardless of what value you give `y`. What you might be looking for is `In[59]:= ExtendedGCD[5, 42]

Out[59]= {1, {17, -2}}`

Comment: Excellent point!  So this ExtendedGCD function just gives 1 sample set of output?  I mean if this were NOT a mod problem, then there would only be the 1 result-set.  Also note the syntax is:  {g, {a, b}} = ExtendedGCD[5, 42]     BTW, any ideas why often I need to close down the kernel as my above screenshot showed?

Comment: `ExtendedGCD[a, b, c, ...]` solves the equation $\gcd(a, b, c, \dots) = an_1 + bn_2 + cn_3 + \cdots$ and returns `{GCD[a, b, c, ...], {n1, n2, n3, ...}}`. The only reason you needed to restart your kernel was because `x` had been previously defined (apparently as `-0.5`) so wherever any expression involving `x` was evaluated, the definition was substituted in instead. Note that `x` is black in your screenshot, which indicates that it has a definition of some kind—undefined symbols are blue. Clearing `x` (`Clear[x]` or `ClearAll[x]`) instead of restarting the kernel would have worked as well.

Comment: ExtendedGCD with two args gives a result that (uniquely) satisfies a certain minimality condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Solve[{3*x + 2*y + 28*z == 9 && 5*x + 27*y + z == 9 && 
   2*x + y + z == 6}, Modulus -> 29]
(*  {{x -> 24, y -> 23, z -> 22}}  *)

Solve[3*x == 5, Modulus -> 6]
(*  {}  *)

Solve[x + x^2 == 2, Modulus -> 8]
(*  {{x -> 1}, {x -> 6}}  *)

Solve[5 x == 1, Modulus -> 42]
(*{{x -> 17}}*)

Solve[{2 x + 7 y == 4, 3 x + 2 y == 9}, Modulus -> 11]
(*  {{x -> 0, y -> 10}}  *)
```

It is actually fun to solve homework problems with pen and paper, why not trying?

Comment: copy pasting: `Solve[3*x == 5, Modulus -> 6]` gives me `{{x -> 1}}` I am on v12.2 Win7.

Comment: @Syed Hmmm, I am on v11.1  for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve[{3*x + 2*y + 28*z == 9 + (29*i), 5*x + 27*y + z == 9 + (29*j), 
  2*x + y + z == 6 + (29*k)}, {x, y, z}, {i, j, k}, Integers, 
 GeneratedParameters -> c]
```

> `{{x -> ConditionalExpression[ 24 + 29 c[1], (c[1] | c[2] | c[3]) ∈ Integers],  y -> ConditionalExpression[ 23 + 29 c[2], (c[1] | c[2] | c[3]) ∈ Integers],  z -> ConditionalExpression[ 22 + 29 c[3], (c[1] | c[2] | c[3]) ∈ Integers]}}`

```
FindInstance[{3*x + 2*y + 28*z == 9 + (29*i), 
  5*x + 27*y + z == 9 + (29*j), 2*x + y + z == 6 + (29*k)}, {x, y, z, 
  i, j, k}, Integers, 1]
```

> `{{x -> 24, y -> 23, z -> 22, i -> 25, j -> 26, k -> 3}}`

```
Solve[x + x^2 == 2 + (8*i), {x}, {i}, Integers, 
 GeneratedParameters -> c]
```

> `{{x -> ConditionalExpression[1 - 8 c[1],  c[1] ∈ Integers]}, {x ->  ConditionalExpression[6 - 8 c[1], c[1] ∈ Integers]}}`